# How to schedule different java classes dynamically?

Tags: java, scheduling

I am trying to write a scheduler class that can schedule different classes set on some user specified timer. I am using

```
ScheduledExecutorService
```

and

```
ScheduleAtFixedRate
```

to do the scheduling.  What I am struggling with is how to tell the scheduler which Java class to schedule.

The idea is that you'd call the scheduler and in the constructor would be some string, which would be the name of the java class you want to schedule.  I have issues using said String in

```
ScheduleAtFixedRate
```

because it requires a runnable.  Any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make your classes implement Runnable interface and pass those instances instead of passing the name of each class and use Reflection ? ( **Please remember to refer to your classes in the receiver part as Runnable, not with your class names** )

**__UPDATE__**

```
public interface Schedulable extends Runnable{
   //In case you need extra API. If not, you don't 
  //need this interface, just use Runnable instead.
}


public class ScheduleAtFixedRate implements Schedulable{
     public void run(){
         // run at fixed rate
     }
}


public class ScheduleAtVariableRate implements Schedulable{
     public void run(){
         // run at fixed rate
     }
}

public class ScheduledExecutorService{
    ...

    public void execute(Schedulable s){
         new Thread(s).start();
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. Use reflection only when you have no other options.

Comment: Suggestion: reword instances of Runnable to implement the Runnable. To be strict, it is not possible to have instance of an interface.

Comment: @user3360241 I disagree. Can you find a better name than "instantiation" for what I do here: `Runnable r = new Runnable() {
 
 @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
};`

Comment: @Alp I will try out your suggestion sometime this week. If it works well, I will mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: @Blaris No worries. I hope it works for you. If you happen to have more questions about it. Just shoot here. I check here whenever I have some time. And I am glad whenever I help. Cheers mate. =]

Comment: @Alp you sound really emotional/intense in the last comment. .. :)

Comment: @Alp you are creating an annonymous class that inplements Runnable and returning reference to instance of that class. You are not creating an instance of Runnable.

Comment: @user3360241 OK. Let's look at the receiver side of it: assume we have a method signature like `private void execute(Runnable r)`. As far as this method is concerned, r is an instance or Runnable, isn't it?

Comment: @Alp here is a simple test. Try to write this - Runnable r = new Runnable(); Compiler will give you error: cannot instantiate Runnable. Cant be more precise :) Using default construtor is not possible as you can see. Nope, r is an instance of class that inplementa Runnable. You don't have to listen to me, but this is how it works and i am simply giving you suggestion how to make good answer even better.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my expression. =] And thank you for being precise and strict. =]

Comment: @Alp what do you mean by pass those instances of Runnable instead?  I have implemented Runnable (pretty easy), but am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two classes

```
public class ABC  extends TimerTask{ 
@Override
public void run()
{/*some code*/}


public class XYZ extends TimerTask{
@Override
public void run()
{/*some code*/}
}
```

And then from some class

```
public class ScheduleTheTask{

public static void main(String[] args) {
begin("com.ABC",new Date(),3000);
begin("com.XYZ",new Date(),3000);
}

   public static void begin(String task , Date startTime,long timeInMillisecons)


     {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(task);
//BIG assumption that only TimerTask  subclasses would be passed add a instanceof check
                TimerTask taskObj= (TimerTask)clazz.newInstance();
                setStartTimeAndInterval();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskObj, startTime,timeInMillisecons);

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map with some task_key (some string) as key and value as your worker thread i.e. `Runnable`

Below is one such example

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduleTask {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    public void schedule(String task) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Current Time = "+new Date());
        scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(getTasks().get(task), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(30000);
    }

    public void waitForTaskToComplete() {
        scheduledThreadPool.shutdown();
        while(!scheduledThreadPool.isTerminated()){
            //wait for all tasks to finish
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

    public Map<String, Runnable> getTasks() {
        Map<String, Runnable> tasks = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
        tasks.put("task1", new WorkerThread("task1"));
        tasks.put("task2", new WorkerThread("task2"));
        return tasks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduleTask scheduleTask = new ScheduleTask();
        scheduleTask.schedule("task1");
        scheduleTask.schedule("task2");

    }
}
```